# Connection to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I am having trouble configuring my connection. I have a getConnection method that looks like this: protected function getConnection(){

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
   }
 }
```

within every test function I am forced to implement the following code to get connection to the database: `$mysqli = new mysqli('xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');`

how do I call the getConnection() method in a more correct manner? I have tried things such as: `$mysqli=parent::getConnection();` but I always get error messages stating that the method is undefined. Any thoughts?

Comment: is dis php ? if yes tag it

Comment: if not you would have tests sharing a connection, which would make them dependent which is a bad idea

Comment: if you are referring to php_unit  check this out http://phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/database.html

Comment: Your test case will also have to extend PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase

Answer (score 0):

If your connection is shared between several functions, and that's usually the case since you want to connect to your database only *once by page call* and not *once by function call*, then create your mysqli object in a persistant scope, not in a function scope.

Then you access it as a function parameter, a [parent] class attribute or a global variable depending on your code.